# Laser scanner implementation

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey everyone,

I wanted to know how to add and implement a laser scanner / laser scanner plugin to my robot. The data of the scanner shall be passed to rviz by using ROS messages.

I got a Gazebo standalone installation with ROS installed afterwards.

My robot so far consists of a moveable base which I can move around through ROS cmd_vel messages. The control is implemented via a gazebo model plugin.
As a first step I added a sensor to my sdf file with the data of our real laser scanner. But now I need the logic for an appropriate gazebo plugin (no point cloud).

Thanks

Christoph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2914/laser-scanner-implementation/) by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 141 on 2013-05-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-29**:
sorry, I am unable to help you to answer this question. Could you please help me how to move around using cmd_vel? I am doing this step currently also. thank you

**Comment by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) on 2013-05-30**:
Hi! Can you make that a real question please. Because the text limit in comments is quiet low and the answer maybe interest other people too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

what I did is: I installed the whole drcsim package and linked directly to the libgazebo_ros_laser.so. That may not be the best solution, but for the time being that will work for me.

Thanks for your help.

---

Originally posted by [Christoph](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/298/christoph/) with karma: 141 on 2013-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0